# Simple question on subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If we have to proof that $H$, a subset of a set $G$, is a subgroup of $G$. Do we first have to proof that $G$ is a group, or would it suffice to proof that $H$ is a group and a subset of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two sets $G$ and $H$ such that $H\subseteq G$, to show that $H$ is a *subgroup* of $G$, it must first be the case that $G$ is a *group*. If $H$ is a group with respect to some operation, and $G$ is not a group with respect to the same operation, then $H$ is *not* a subgroup of $G$; it is just a group. If, as an exercise, you are told to show that "$H$ is a subgroup of $G$", then it is safe to assume that $G$ is a group.

Comment: Then again, if they would be really annoying they could deduct point because you assume something is trivial, but it might not be according to their definition of trivial. Ohw well, proving that a group is a group isn't that much work anyway.